# Audible popping when pausing some HTML5 <audio>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

Why does the audio on certain files 'pop' or 'click' when the hoverstate is left, but not on others? Popping can be observed [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f9rEu/2/) (JSFiddle). You may have to hover and then unhover a few times to hear it. Even when the file is converted to .ogg, it still pops on hover exit (though it is significantly more responsive).

```
var test = new Audio("test.ogg");
$('#test').hover(function() {
  test.play();
}, function() {
  test.pause();
  test.currentTime = 0;
});
```

Is there any way to resolve this? Is it the audio file itself? Is there a way to programmatically prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is not using pause or play but rather let the sound play in loop, and fades in / out when the mouse enters/leaves.

The fading is done progressively by a function called every 20ms. This function will reduce the difference between a targetVolume and the actual sample volume.

http://jsfiddle.net/f9rEu/5/

```
var test = new Audio("http://www.sounddogs.com/previews/25/mp3/228367_SOUNDDOGS__dr.mp3");

test.loop = true ;
test.play();
fade(0);

$('#test').hover(function() {
    fade(1);
    return;
}, function() {
    fade(0);
    return;
});


var targetVolume = 0;
var volumeIncrease = 0.0023 ; // in percent per millisecond

function fade( dest ) {
   targetVolume = dest ;
}

var lastTime = Date.now();
function fader() {
    var now= Date.now() ;
    var dt = now - lastTime ;
    lastTime = now;
    var diff = targetVolume - test.volume ;
    if (diff == 0 ) return;
    if (Math.abs ( diff )  < 5* volumeIncrease*dt ) {
        test.volume = targetVolume ;
        return ;
    }
    var chg = (diff > 0) ?  volumeIncrease : - volumeIncrease ;
    chg *=  dt ;
    var newTestVolume = test.volume + chg;    
    test.volume = newTestVolume ;
}

setInterval(fader, 20);
```

Edit : 
I had only tried on desktop/Chrome, and it was ok, i just tested Safari ok, but for instance on Firefox it is in did a mess.

Out of curiosity, i wondered if it was because of the way the mp3 buffer was handled, and indeed the sound is clean if you use a .wav as input.
For a short looping ambient sound, .wav is ok.
For a longer sound, i guess the file size would be just too high.

I did not test on mobile devices, but their audio is so laggy that i wouldn't bet...

Here's a fiddle using a wav : http://jsfiddle.net/f9rEu/20/

Notice that you might use   [webAudio](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html)   that is a low latency html5 Audio API that allows a LOT of sound processing.
You might look here if its support is ok for the browsers/devices you target :
http://caniuse.com/audio-api

Comment: Points for effort and creating a concept, but this actually introduces even more popping than the original. I blame the slowness of JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: @daveycroqet Thanks, i edited to suggest some other ways to deal with this issue.

Answer (score 5):

The "popping" phenomenon is inevitable whenever you play an audio file and then turn it's volume abruptly to zero.

Sound is vibration, vibration is encoded as a value in a sound sample, and this value is most likely different than zero (say an arbitrary value "x").

So when the sound goes from "x" to 0, this represents another very short "vibration" that has an audible audio effect.
Same thing happena when the playing resumes, going from 0 to another "y" value (which is the value of the "vibration" in the next samples). this "movement" creates an audible "pop".

The more X or Y are "far from zero", the more audible the pop will be. This could explain the varability of the phenomenon among different files.

You can avoid this effect only if you do a gradual fade-out (also a few milliseconds) of the volume when stopping and a gradual fade-in when resuming.

Forgive me for the oversimplification of the language and the physics, I've tried to be understandable.

Comment: the phenomenon you're talking does not apply for a around half a second effect... If it was not enough, it occurs on FF + Ch, but not on Sf (i just tested latest version of those with latest mac OS)...

Comment: @GameAlchemist: maybe Sf implements (like *many* software players like VLC actually do, for example) a form of fade-in and fade-out by itself when stopping or resuming?

Comment: For the "short" effect: this most likely happens because THAT sound starts and ends smoothly to zero, while other samples may start or end abruptly. (or it happens when you pause-resume the sound if the player doesn't implement that fade in/out mechanism).
I've some experience in sound mixing, It's common practice when cutting audio files to insert manually insert those "fades" in music records when you cut'n'paste audio in order to avoide those "pops".

Comment: This is very informative, and I thank you for that, but how would I go about 'fading' the audio programmatically via HTML5/JS/jQuery/whatever to preserve the hover effect without the popping?