# 'Pop noise' sounds when audio paused with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I have an audio tag in my html, and which I have .wav inside it. With Javascript, I select audio tag and play the wav., which I trigger using a keyboard key. *What I am trying to achieve is, for example, on press of each 'A' key, replay the .wav/play the sound from the beginning)*

The playing of the audio works okay, and so does the pause too. However, I get a pop noise, while directly pausing the playing .wav.

```
var audio = document.getElementById(sound);

if (!isPlaying(audio)) {
   audio.play();     // works
} else {
   audio.pause();    // pops on this line; I checked with commenting below lines.
   audio.currentTime = 0;
   audio.play();
}
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21525308/4705339), and as far as I understand, it's happening because I instantly set the volume to 0; but I couldn't figure it out for my case. I believe using a fader with setInterval is not a good approach

I also found `audio.muted = true`, and tried using it before pausing the volume (and used `audio.muted = false` just before playing the audio), but this also gives pop noise

---

Update:

I think I need to use fade out to work around this issue. Is there a way to fade out audio instantly?

Comment: *I believe using a fader with setInterval is not a good approach* Why not?

Comment: I am not sure as I said.. I need to play 3 second audios as well as 0.2 second shots; not only sample-shots.. That's why I thought setting an interval and triggering fade-out accordingly will not let me have a generic code for both 3 second and 0.2 second audios. If it's a good approach, can you please clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Update:
>
> I think I need to use fade out to work around this issue. Is there a
>   way to fade out audio instantly?

You can use `.animate()` to animate `volume` property from current value to `0`

```js
var audio = $("audio");
$("button").click(function() {
  if (audio[0].volume > 0) {
    audio.animate({volume:0});
    // call `.pause()` here
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio controls  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6e/Micronesia_National_Anthem.ogg"></audio>
<button>fade out audio</button>
```

Comment: That's very cool, does this animation need the `controls=true`?

Comment: @zer00ne _"does this animation need the `controls=true`"_ No

Comment: I didn't set a volume priorly. What is the default volume level to bring it back?

Comment: @senty _"What is the default volume level"_ Try `console.log(audio[0].volume);` before `if` condition