# Fade out audio instantly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

In short: I have a playing audio. On key-press I want to fade out the audio instantly, as soon as I press. All the information I found is fading out the audio with an interval regarding to the duration, such as `audio.duration - 2` *seconds*. However, I want to fade out instantly.

To expand: I asked another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38387226/pop-noise-sounds-when-audio-paused-with-javascript), regarding to my main problem. I tried `audio.pause` approach, but it's giving me 'pop' noise. From my research, I think it's the sound of 'instantly setting playing audio's volume to 0'. That's why I thought 'fade-out' would be a workaround to achieve what I am trying.

Comment: Should `.puase()` be called when `.volume` is `0`?

Answer (score 3):

Given an audio element, you could try something like this :

```
var fadeInterval = setInterval(function(){
    if(audio.volume <= 0){
        clearInterval(fadeInterval);
        return;
    }
    audio.volume -= 0.1;
}, 2);
```

Where `audio` is an html5 audio element.

You can adjust the delay, in miliseconds, by replacing `2` with any value you want.

You can adjust the amount of decreasing by replacing `0.1` with any value you want, between 0 and 1.

## Edit

The code below should be more reliable

```
function fade(){
    if(audio.volume > 0){
        audio.volume -= 0.1;
        setTimeout(fade, 2);
    }else{
        audio.pause();
    }
}
```

[Try it here](https://jsfiddle.net/rv90a719/)